# How Can I move Search bar in Navigation div in Magento2 using XML

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, magento-2.0

How Can I move Search bar section in Navigation div Magento2 using XML.

I have used below code but it's not working:

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" before="-"/>
```

Any one have idea for how to move search bar in Navigation div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has work for me

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-"/>
```

It has moved the search div inside on navigation ul

Comment: Yes my requirement is move search in navigation div.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following line into `yourtheme/layout/default.xml`

```
<move element="top.search" destination="navigation.sections" after="catalog.topnav" />
```

Copy `sections.phtml` from `module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/sections.phtml` to `yourtheme/templates/html/sections.phtml`

Now open this file and put the following line of code after `class="section-items"` DIV

```
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('topSearch'); ?>
```

This is working for me.

Comment: We are just moving the section then why we need to call `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('topSearch'); ?>` in section file?

Comment: @Zaheerabbas, I was not aware of this when I had started digging into Magento 2 late 2015

Answer (score 4):

This has worked for me

```
<move element="top.search" destination="catalog.topnav" after="-" />
```

It has moved the search div inside on `nav`.

Comment: For me, its in the UL-element, not in nav. Im using Magento 2.1.3. An idea whats wrong here?

Comment: This works ish, but when on mobile view it would be in the side menu. (Weltpixel theme) Might need it to go up a level or two in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need put search box after navigation block and use css to make display it in one line, beckouse html/topmenu.phtml block don't print their child's

```
<move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav" />
```

or overwrite html/topmenu.phtml to

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>

<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?php echo $_menu; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>
</nav>
```

Also feel free to create issue on github or create pull request with fix.

Comment: Thanks for reply,

I have tried both way but it's not working properly.
Currently Search section in "header content" div. I need search div in  **<nav class="navigation" role="navigation"> </nav>**

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps. It works on Mag2.3 version

1. Open default.xml file ( app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml) and add this code( `<move element="top.search" destination="store.menu" after="-" />` )

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
         <move element="top.search" destination="store.menu" after="-" />
</body>
</page>
```

2. Go to admin > system > cache management and flush cache.

Answer (score 0):

To move the search bar from header to the colored navigation menu (with category links), you just have to:

1. create a file: `src/app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
2. put this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Move top.search in navigation menu -->
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="configProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Search\ViewModel\ConfigProvider</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. then copy: `/src/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` to your theme `src/app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`
4. in `topmenu.phtml` replace

```php
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </ul>
```

with

```php
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
    </ul>
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('top.search') ?>
```

5. regenerate static files